# Chinese province coordinates in r

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, r-sp

Does anyone knows how to access the coordinates by regions for China. The code below shows the same thing that I am looking for China. Many thanks in advance

```
require(maps)
 states_map <- map_data("state")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check the following approach:

```r
# load packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(osmextract)

# get polygons in china
poly_china <- openstreetmap_fr_zones[which(openstreetmap_fr_zones$parent == "china"), ]

# extract the coords and save the coords in a data.frame
# you may want to keep the data in matrix format for better performances
poly_china_coords <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(poly_china))

# extract the region name
my_times <- vapply(st_geometry(poly_china), function(x) nrow(st_coordinates(x)), numeric(1))
poly_china_coords$region_name <- rep(poly_china$name, times = my_times)

# result
head(poly_china_coords)
#>         X      Y L1 L2 L3 region_name
#> 1 114.875 32.960  1  1  1       Anhui
#> 2 114.860 32.970  1  1  1       Anhui
#> 3 114.870 33.025  1  1  1       Anhui
#> 4 114.880 33.035  1  1  1       Anhui
#> 5 114.895 33.035  1  1  1       Anhui
#> 6 114.890 33.060  1  1  1       Anhui
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can install `sf` from CRAN and you can install `osmextract` as follows:

```r
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("ITSLeeds/osmextract")
```

The data are stored using the EPSG:4326 so X = long and Y = lat.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are seeking for?

```
 map_data("world",region="China")

      long      lat group order region subregion
1 110.8888 19.99194     1     1  China         1
2 110.9383 19.94756     1     2  China         1
3 110.9707 19.88330     1     3  China         1
4 110.9977 19.76470     1     4  China         1
5 111.0137 19.65547     1     5  China         1
6 110.9127 19.58608     1     6  China         1
```

Comment: I need the coordinates of the polygons